# Trying to find a novel about a multigenerational ship crossing space

Tags: story-identification, novel, generation-ship

Looking for a story I read years ago about a multigenerational ship traveling across space and about to cross a huge expanse of emptiness, in a nutshell part of the crew takes over the ship and forces it to turn around and head back to Earth, help!

Answer (score 10):

[*The Dark Beyond the Stars*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2172) by [Frank M. Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_M._Robinson). The book has a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Beyond_the_Stars) page. It won a [Lambda Literary Award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lambda_Literary_Awards_winners_and_nominees_for_science_fiction,_fantasy_and_horror) for gay SF/F. Here is the back cover blurb from the [1992 Tor paperback edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?37857):

> **TO SEEK THE STARS
> IS MANKIND'S DESTINY
> —BUT ONLY ONE MAN
> KNOWS WHEN TO RETURN!**
> For two thousand years, the starship *Astron* has searched the galaxy for alien lifeforms—without success. Now, just as the ship is falling apart, the only direction left to explore is across the Dark, a one-hundred-generation journey through empty space, into a rich new region of stars. The ship's captain—immortal, obsessed—refuses to abandon the quest. He will cross the Dark—or destroy them all trying.
> Only Sparrow, a young crewman uncertain of his own past, can stand against the captain and turn the ship around. But can even he resist the lure and the challenge of . . .
> **The Dark Beyond the Stars**